# Writing to a file in c, garbage value gets populated

Tags: c, io, fwrite

The code is supposed to append whatever data it gets in fileReceived to a.txt file but instead it gets populated with random values.(well not so random also but definitely not the correct values). Am i missing out on something?

```
File *fp;
fp = fopen("a.txt",+a);
while(1)
{
    fileReceived =...// getting char array of 1024 size
    fwrite(fileReceived,1,sizeof(fileReceived),fp);

    if(padding!=0)
    {
      fclose(fp);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: who is setting padding ? where did you define fileReceived ?

Comment: `sizeof(fileReceived)` is probably not 1024 but size of pointer.

Comment: As in this correct, what I have written?

Comment: you've hidden the important part: fileReceived =...// getting char array of 1024 size

Comment: padding gets set to 1 for the last data received by filereceived.

Comment: ok so that could be the error?  fileReceived = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    memset(fileReceived,'\0', 1024);   filereceived is defined as follows. it gets value from say somefunction and its always 1024 bytes(well atleast its supposed to be)

Comment: check my answer. `sizeof()` doesn't work for dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing (but can't be otherwise) even if you're not showing the right part:

```
fileReceived =...// getting char array of 1024 size
fwrite(fileReceived,1,sizeof(fileReceived),fp);
```

`fileReceived` *has to be* a pointer on data, so `sizeof(fileReceived)` isn't 1024 but 4 or 8 depending on your architecture (since it's not possible to assign an array to another array)

You're writing too few data in your loop and your file gets the first values but not the last ones. Since you know the size, fix it like this:

```
int size = 1024;
...
fwrite(fileReceived,1,size,fp);
```

if the data size varies, you *have* to get the size information from whatever function provides the pointer to you, or you'll get *undefined behaviour*

Comment: thank you. you were right for both the cases. I was using 1024 only earlier.

Comment: I checked the data and the last packet is not of size 1024. sorry I couldn't properly post all the details, its for an assignment and hence I can't post the entire code.

Comment: no problem. The last packet must be a special case where you change the size of the `fwrite`, that's all. but you have to know the size, either full size (so you can substract 1024 until the size is lower than that) or at each iteration.

Comment: yes I am trying to do that only now. Thanks for your help Jean.